# Filter array of objects that contains string using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a value and i need to return the objects that contains this value in propertie.

```
var search='CPP@';
var results=_.filter(collection,{VAL:search});
```

I need to grab all objects that constains 'CPP@' , not the equals.
I've prepared a https://jsfiddle.net/licass/e87mxfqt/

Answer (score 20):

```js
var collection=[
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 4",
    "VAL": "CPP@4@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 5",
    "VAL": "CMIP@5@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 6",
    "VAL": "CMIP@6@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 7",
    "VAL": "CMIP@7@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 8",
    "VAL": "CPP@8@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 9",
    "VAL": "CMIP@9@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 10",
    "VAL": "CMIP@10@1900-01-01"
  }
 
];
 var search='CPP@';
    var results=_.filter(collection,function(item){
    return item.VAL.indexOf(search)>-1;
    });
    console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

```
 var search='CPP@';
    var results=_.filter(collection,function(item){
    return item.VAL.indexOf(search)>-1;
    });
    console.log(results);
```

Comment: how to count the number of returned items

Comment: var count = results.length

Answer (score 14):

```
var results = _.filter(collection,function(obj) {
    return obj.VAL.indexOf(search) !== -1;
});
```

*update from 2022*

You don't even need `lodash` now:

```
collection.filter(o => o.VAL.includes(search));
```

We now may use `.filter` method for arrays and `.includes` for arrays and strings. And arrow functions, of course!

Comment: Would be better if you add some explanation!

Answer (score -3):

```js
var collection=[
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 4",
    "VAL": "CPP@4@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 5",
    "VAL": "CMIP@5@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 6",
    "VAL": "CMIP@6@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 7",
    "VAL": "CMIP@7@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 8",
    "VAL": "CPP@8@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 9",
    "VAL": "CMIP@9@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "DSP_MAQ": "Máquina 10",
    "VAL": "CMIP@10@1900-01-01"
  }
 
];
 var search='CMIP@9@1900-01-01';
var filterList = collection.filter(function(item) {
 return item.VAL === search;
})
console.log(filterList)
```

use javascirpt filter.

Comment: This is not 'contains' - this is 'equals'